# SQL Desc column name not accepted?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert, mysql-error-1064

I've have created a SQL database, which I'm connected to with MySQL Workbench. I have one column that I for some reason can't use in the query, which Workbench actually recognize. My Query looks looked like this:

```
INSERT INTO `mcfluid` (desc, type, maxcap, curcap) VALUES ('tank', 'water',1000,1000);
```

This didn't work for some reason, but when I changed it to this:

```
INSERT INTO `mcfluid` (`desc`, type, maxcap, curcap) VALUES ('tank', 'lava',1000,1000);
```

It for some reason did?

Why is this?

My table looks like this:

```
id int(11) AI PK 
desc varchar(100) 
type varchar(100) 
maxcap bigint(20) 
curcap bigint(20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`desc` is a reserved word in SQL - it's a keyword for the `order by` clause that denotes the ordering in a **desc**ing order (e.g.: `select * from mytable order by mycolumn DESC`).

Escaping it with backticks allows MySQL to understand you've meant to use it as a name and not a syntactic element.

Comment: Oh this worked! just changed it to another name then, and problem fixed